# Strictly convert string to int

Tags: string, go, hex

I am trying to store a hexadecimal string value : ex "3958ABBFEC23BD40" to uint64 which would like this:

```
fmt.Println(myuint64)

$ 0x3958ABBFEC23BD40
```

I have tried using encoding/hex, or strconv to int, etc... I couldn't find any solution.

```
file, err := os.Open("myfile")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("erreur",err)
}
b := bufio.NewReader(file)
a,_ := b.Peek(16)
d, err := strconv.ParseUint(string(a), 0, 64)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%d\n%s\n", d,string(a))
```

Obviously I am not getting the result expected :

```
$ 4132241498901298496
fcb9ca7c63ec7c5d
```

expected :

```
$ 0xfcb9ca7c63ec7c5d
```

using the following code, I have retrieve the good uint, but I can't convert it to hexa, unless by using strconv, but I don't wish to work with a string.

```
v := *(*[8]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&d))
var final []byte = v[:]
var n uint64
buf := bytes.NewBuffer(final)
binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &n)
fmt.Println(strconv.FormatUint(n, 16))
```

result : `$ fcb9ca7c63ec7c5d` but as string, and expected `$ fcb9ca7c63ec7c5d` type of uint64...

Comment: Go doesn't support type casting. Even if it did, converting a string to int is never a casting operation, it's a conversion.

Comment: But include the code you've tried, and explain what specific problem you're facing.

Comment: If you've tried something and it didn't work, post that in the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [strconv.ParseUint](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseUint).

```golang
d, err := strconv.ParseUint("0x3958ABBFEC23BD40", 0, 64)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%d\n", d)
```

You can try this code out on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/p9xg1AI0wxE).